# Provisioning profile not being show while making ipa file in iphone app

Tags: iphone, profiling, ios-provisioning

I am making ipad file in xocde when we archive app while asking for code signing identity it is not showing the provisioning which i have set in build setings.
In build setting it comes list but now while archiving the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check in keychain access your provisional profile is validate or not.and open the keychain and go to category and select certificate if the certificate is appear then it validate